# Why does the water not flow after replacing the filter in my Samsung fridge

Tags: water, refrigerator, filter

I have been very frustrated with my Samsung fridge water dispenser.  I replaced the filter and turned on the water.  It worked for a while (a few hours) and then stopped working and I would have to go through the routine of taking out the filter, putting it back in and turning on the water again to get it working.  I have read all the blogs and couldn’t work out the problem.  Eventually a technician found some information that the water dispenser is sensitive to water pressure and if the water pressure is too high it forms a block.  Have now turned the valve half way and it has worked!

Comment: Normally a good fridge has its own pressure regulator. Yours might not. You can install a 30 PSI pressure regulator in the water supply line to the fridge.

Comment: You have what we refer to as a "self-answered question". Please [edit] your question to take the answer "turn the supply valve down half-way" and make an answer out of that. You'll probably get up votes on it, and can accept it as an answer if no better suggestions come along.